# Counting repeating sequences Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data scattered in a chaotic manner.

```
store_id  period_id  sales_volume
0        4186684        226       1004.60
1        5219836        226        989.00
2        4185865        226        827.45
3        4186186        226        708.40
4        4523929        226        690.75
5        4186441        226        592.55    
...          ...        ...           ...
846960  11710234        195          0.60
846961  11693671        236          0.60
846962  27105667        212          0.60
846963  11693725        201          0.60
846964  27078031        234          0.60
846965  11663800        231          0.60
```

In the `period_id` column the values give an indication of how long the process lasted only if they go continuously, as soon as the series is interrupted, this means that a new period has started. This representation of periods is relevant for each `store_id`.
Since I could not sort the data in order I present them as an example below:

```
          store_id    period_id    sales_volume
0          4168621        208        1004.60
1          4168621        209        989.00   #end of period
2          4168621        211        827.45
3          4168621        212        708.40
4          4168621        213        690.75
5          4168621        214        592.55   #end of period
6          41685          208        4634
7          41685          209        3356563  #end of period
```

I've grouped the values by store_id:

`df.groupby('store_id').agg(lambda x: x.tolist())`

and received

```
store_id  sales_volume                        period_id  

4168621   [226, 202, 199, 204, 224, 193  ...  [27.45,10.0,8.15,7.6, ...
4168624   [226, 216, 215, 225, 214, 217  ...  [429.8, 131.35,92.0   ...
4168636   [226, 217, 238, 223, 234, 240, ...  [33.30, 9.3, 6.4,     ...
4168639   [226, 204, 211, 208, 232, 207, ...  [19.3,8.05, 6.5, 6.4, ...
...       ...                                 ...
```

It turns out, I need to sort the values in `period_id` somehow in order to calculate the number of sequences that turned out for each `store_id`, that is, as in code 2. It shows 3 sequences

Don't know how I can do it...

Comment: Copy contents of your pictures into `code blocks` so it is easier to follow your question. You should get more attention this way.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke done. Thank you

Comment: @SzymonMaszke Done!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to sort by `period_id` within each `store_id`, you can use `df.sort_values`. Using your example DataFrame as input:

```
df.sort_values(['store_id', 'period_id']).reset_index(drop=True)

df
   store_id  period_id  sales_volume
0     41685        208       4634.00
1     41685        209    3356563.00
2   4168621        208       1004.60
3   4168621        209        989.00
4   4168621        211        827.45
5   4168621        212        708.40
6   4168621        213        690.75
7   4168621        214        592.55
```

If you want to detect each period (and then group by period, for example), here is one way:

```
df['period_group'] = df['period_id'].diff().fillna(1).ne(1).astype(int).cumsum()

df
   store_id  period_id  sales_volume  period_group
0   4168621        208       1004.60             0
1   4168621        209        989.00             0
2   4168621        211        827.45             1
3   4168621        212        708.40             1
4   4168621        213        690.75             1
5   4168621        214        592.55             1
6     41685        208       4634.00             2
7     41685        209    3356563.00             2
```

You can then group by this new column `period_group` to analyze "runs" of contiguous period ids.

Comment: Yeah and how can I found a volume of sales for each period, not for each period_group value?

Comment: Do you mean the sum of `sales_volume` across all `store_id`s for each `period_id`?

Comment: I mean sum of `sales_volume` for each `period_group`

Comment: The `period_group` column is designed for the usual `groupby` usage. Try something like `df.groupby('period_group')['sales_volume'].sum()`.